# How to place scroll bar on side of table?

Tags: html, css

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/m4HB3/

I have a scrolling table with fixed headers which is working correctly. The problem I am having is where the scroll bar is placed, it is placed sligthly underneath the last column which causes it to take up some of the last column space and thus moves the other columns off alignment.

My question is how can I clip the scroll bar to the right of the table so it does not affect taking up column space?

Below is html of sample table:

```
<table id="tableqanda" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%" class="questionno">Question No.</th>
        <th width="27%" class="question">Question</th>
        <th width="7%" class="option">Option Type</th>
        <th width="11%" class="image">Image</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
    <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tableqandarow">
<td width="5%" class="questionno">1</td>
<td width="27%" class="question">What is a RAM?</td>
<td width="7%" class="option">A-E</td>
<td width="11%" class="imagetd"><ul class="qandaul"><li>Lighthouse_4.jpg</li></ul></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableqandarow">
<td width="5%" class="questionno">2</td>
<td width="27%" class="question">Name 3 car maneuvers you may do in a test?</td>
<td width="7%" class="option">A-F</td>
<td width="11%" class="imagetd"><ul class="qandaul"><li>Tulips_3.jpg</li></ul></td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Below is css:

```
#tableqanda_onthefly_container
{
    width:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height:500px;
}

#tableqanda_onthefly
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    clear:both;
}

#tableqanda_onthefly td
{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#tableqanda, #tableqanda_onthefly{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}       

#tableqanda{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    float:left;
}

#tableqanda td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#tableqanda th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}

.tableqandarow{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: Add `overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;` to `#tableqanda_onthefly` like you have on `#tableqanda_onthefly_container`.

Comment: @Mooseman I will give it a try ... tried it did not work

Comment: Change both instances of `overflow-y: scroll` to `overflow-y: auto`.

Comment: @Mooseman I tried this but did not work, I included it in fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/m4HB3/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4HB3/29/

I simply wrapped your `table` into a container `div` with an ID of `container`, removed your `overflow` properties from the table and set the following on the containing div (you can change the height to whatever you want, I just left it as 75 to demonstrate):

```
#container
{
    height: 75px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

**EDIT: After a few tweaks, this is what he wanted http://jsfiddle.net/m4HB3/37/**

Comment: You are 90% there, only issue is I do not want the scroll bar on the side to be placed next to the table heading, want to place next to the td tags. I tried moving the div above the second table but it doesn't like that as no content displayed. But if you can get it placed by the  side of the td tags only then bounty is yours

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, it will let me award bounty in 23 hours so I will give you bounty tommorow

Comment: @user1830984 No problems, glad I could help!

Comment: If you don't mide can you look at this fiddle, I just implemnted what you have done but included extra columns, it looks a little messy but do you know what is causing the bad alignment between the table headings and the table column? This is just a favour I am asking if you don't mind? http://jsfiddle.net/m4HB3/57/

Comment: @user1830984 Sure, try this fiddle that looks a lot neater http://jsfiddle.net/m4HB3/58/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attempt but it still doesn't seem aligned, if you look at the table columns, they are not aligned with their table headings. I wil/ changed the content from words to numbers in the fiddle and you can see what I mean. Each number means that the column and the heading with the same number must have their column aligned with each other

Comment: @user1830984 Try this, you had spelt `width` wrong on your second table: http://jsfiddle.net/m4HB3/61/

Comment: OMG, This shows that it is time to go to sleep now lol. You seem alright even though its 1:40 am in the UK haha. Thanks again buddy :)

Comment: @user1830984 I think you're right lol, I'm suprisingly sharp at this time of the **morning** :|

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly addressing your specific goal but as a work around, you can add an additional TD to the end of the header and set it to the width of the scrollbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/m4HB3/28/

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%" class="questionno">Question No.</th>
        <th width="27%" class="question">Question</th>
        <th width="7%" class="option">Option Type</th>
        <th width="11%" class="image">Image</th>
        **<th width="8px" class=""></th>**
    </tr>
</thead>
```

This would at least make it appear more presentable.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753238/fixed-header-and-scrollable-body) I have a complete explanation of CSS tables + scroll + Browsers

I hope you find it useful